# Javascript post method XHR request to PHP fails

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to do a simple post to a PHP page using JavaScript's XHR in Chrome (latest). I am getting errors - specifically, the test.php page I am calling (in the same folder as my JS code, locally), is showing as a failed http response. Chrome Dev Tools shows as 'Failed to load response data'.

test.php

```
<?php
echo 'this string should return';
?>
```

ajax.js

```
createXHR: function () {
        if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (typeof ActiveXObject !== 'undefined') {
            if (typeof arguments.callee.activeXString !== 'string') {
                var versions = ['MSXML2.XMLHttp.6.0', 'MSXML2.XMLHttp.3.0',
                    'MSXML2.XMLHttp'],
                        i,
                        len;
                for (i = 0, len = versions.length; i < len; i++) {
                    try {
                        new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                        arguments.callee.activeXString = versions[i];
                        break;
                    } catch (ex) {
                        //skip
                    }
                }
            }
            return new ActiveXObject(arguments.callee.activeXString);
        } else {
            throw new Error('No XHR object available.');
        }
    },

var xhr = AJAX.createXHR();

        /**
         *  @event onreadystatechange
         *  @description DOM Level 0 event fired when readyState property is changed
         */
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            /** @param {Number} readyState 0 - Uninitialized, 1- Open, 2- Sent, 3- Receiving, 4- Complete */
            if (xhr.readyState === 4) {

                console.log(xhr.status); //prints 0

                if ((xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) || xhr.status === 304) {
                    AJAX.success(xhr.responseText);
                } else {
                    //fail
                    AJAX.fail();
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.open('post', 'test.php', true);

        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        xhr.send('name=myname&email=myemail');
```

I can GET this page, so I can definitely see the page on the same origin, but the POST just doesn't seem to work. I have set the Content-Type, set async as true, set the method as post, and the file name is correct. I tried using return in my php file, and print_r and echo - no dice.

Why is the response not coming through at all? It just gets through to readyState = 4 = Complete, but the xhr.status is 0 (zero). Thoughts?

EDIT:

I am using localhost, run using netbeans.

http://localhost:8383/Coding%20Practice/public_html/index.html

test.php is at http://localhost:8383/Coding%20Practice/public_html/test.php

Comment: And you're using a webserver ?

Comment: You're kind of missing the critical code where you're showing which URL you're trying to get data from. Also, note that your XHR code is at this point ancient and mostly obsolete, since modern versions of IE fully support the XMLHTTPRequest object, and the latest versions of IE don't even allow ActiveX controls anymore (thankfully).

Comment: Like Mike said, you're missing the critical code here. I simply assume that the path to your file is not set up properly. BTW what's the problem about using jquery? $.ajax, $.get, $.post are your friends...

Comment: Jan / Mike - please see the edit, url and explanation is provided. Forget JQuery and non-cross browser compliant code - the question stands apart from those issues.

Comment: This was actually mind boggling simple. @adeneo touched on the answer. Running a local file from netbeans is NOT a server. I thought it acted like a server, but it does not. Running this code through wamp works fine. Nothing wrong with the code - but a good lesson in how stackoverflow answers are filled with Jquery solutions to non-Jquery questions.

Answer (score 0):

Running a local file from netbeans is NOT a server. I thought it acted like a server, but it does not. Running this code through wamp works fine.